# JDBC resultset close

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, c3p0

I am doing profiling of my Java application and found some interesting statistics for a jdbc PreparedStatement call:

Given below is the environment details:
Database: Sybase SQL Anywhere 10.0.1
Driver: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
connection pool: c3p0
JRE: 1.6.0_05

The code in question is given below:

```
try {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setDouble(...);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
              ......

    return xyz;
}
finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null) rs.close();
        if (ps != null) ps.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlEx) {

    }
}
```

From JProfiler stats, I find that this particular resultspace.close() statement alone takes a large amount of time. It varies from 25 ms to 320s while for other code blocks which are of identical in nature, i find that this takes close to 20 microseconds.

Just to be sure, I ran this performance test multiple times and confirmed this data. I am puzzled by this behaviour - Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of SQL do you execute: INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT/Stored procedure call? Is there autocommit? You wrote about other code block that runs quickly: do it differ only in SQL or there is other difference?

Comment: One comment on your code: you should invoke the "close()" methods in separate try blocks, otherwise "ps.close()" is not sure to be called and you won't even notice since there is no handling of the potential exception.

Comment: @Michal: 
The SQL is a simple select statement. 

@the-banana-king:
good point. - we are in the process of refactoring code to spring jdbc so i am hoping that would take care of it.

Comment: 320 seconds? 320s might be a DNS timeout? TCP/IP wont have a time to live (TTL) above 255s.

Comment: Do you fully consume the result set in all cases (that is call rs.next() until it doesn't return anything anymore)?

Answer (score 3):

This performance is JDBC driver specific. The C3P0 connection pool should not have any influence on it. I would suggest to retest it with a newer or another JDBC driver. An alternative to the Sybase driver is the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). I am not sure how this performs compared to the Sybase driver, but it is known to be *very* performant as compared to Microsoft's own MSSQL JDBC driver.

Unrelated to the actual problem, you should in fact call the `close()` methods each in its own `try` block, else there's no guarantee that they will *all* be closed. If the first close throws `SQLException`, the subsequent close calls won't be executed. The [Apache Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html) may help to take the boilerplate code away.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I will give it a shot with the new driver. Regarding the code comment, we have development stories planned where we would be migrating this code to Spring JDBC.

Comment: Multiple `try` blocks will also allow you to get rid of the `null` messiness.

Comment: No, I would disagree with Tom Hawtin and recommend static methods to close.  Wrap those close statements in individual try/catch blocks, and do check for null.  Or just use Spring JDBC.  They wrote it better than you will.

Answer (score 1):

On a semi-related note, check out [Apache Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) and the [Dbutils.closeQuietly()](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.sql.Connection,%20java.sql.Statement,%20java.sql.ResultSet%29) method for easily managing closing of connections/statements/resultsets in the correct order with correct exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Is the method call actually causing CPU load during the delay or is it simply waiting? Closing the ResultSet most likely involves remote communication with the database and my guess is that there are some circumstances where this may take a while.

Comment: Hmm - The database is in a remote location in a different geography. However, there are bunch of Prepared Statements like this in the codebase which seems to execute fine - Only this particular code block seems to have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the statement is a select and you are not consuming all the data try canceling the statement before closing it.